# Unable to change protocol conformance of an object

Tags: swift, protocols

In the code, the `Wheeled` and `Vehicle` are protocols, the `Bike` class conforms to both of the protocols

```
protocol Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
}

protocol Vehicle {
    var maker: String { get }
    var owner: String {get set}
    var ownerKid: String { get }
}


class Bike: Vehicle, Wheeled {
    let numberOfWheels: Int = 0
    var ownerKid: String = "Junior"

    var maker: String {
        return "Ford"
    }

    var owner: String {
        get {
            return "Bob"
        }
        set {
            ownerKid = "\(newValue) Junior"
        }
    }
}

let bike: Bike = Bike()

var theBike: Vehicle = bike // #1
var theBike: Wheeled = bike // #2 error: invalid redeclaration of 'theBike'
```

When I check the properties of `theBike`, in #1, `theBike` object only has the properties conform to the `Vehicle` protocol; while in #2 `theBike` object only has the properties conform to the `Wheeled` properties

Therefore, I feel `theBike` in #1 and #2 is different, why it tells me that invalid redeclaration?

**Question:** how should I change the protocol conformance of an object? Or is it allowed to change the conformance of an object?

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: It's nothing to do with protocols – you just have two identically named local variables. That's invalid.

Comment: because you declare a variable of the same name for a second time which is not allowed.

Comment: `var theBike2: Wheeled = bike` fixes it.

Comment: But if I want to change the protocol conformance of `theBike` from `Vehicle` to `Wheeled`, how should I do that? (I mean without create one more object with different conformance)

Comment: Variables cannot change their type, they can at most change their value.

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you trying to accomplish here? Be precise! Because right now I have absolutely no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: @SLN Why aren't you just using `bike` directly? You lose type information when you upcast, therefore if you don't need to do it, don't do it!

Comment: @luk2302 You maybe a good programmer and very eager to help to tell and to teach, but you are very arrogant, I hope you aware of that. I am new to programming, I actually just started programming for 32 days. There are a lot of things I don't known yet, I don't even know what should I ask sometimes.  I wish you would be a bit nicer for all beginners instead show off how good you are!

Comment: @SLN you are very much wrong! I simply expect *you* to know what you ask. If you do not know what you are asking for then how are we supposed to help? You show us some code which does not work; without stating what you want to achieve; and probably equally important: why you want to achieve what you are trying to. We cannot help you in that situation other than say to **get clear**!

Comment: @luk2302 Anyway, I am still appreciate your reply, actually a lot. be angry is always a bad attitude. I am in the very very dark side of the coding now, got lots to learn and lots of "no idea" moment, in fact, all the time. The way to describe a question in a clean way is not easy. I'm still learning it. Both the English language and the Swift language.  Very sorry for the emotional words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot declare a variable (i.e. with the same name) twice.
- If you need to access the properties of another protocol, use `if let ... as? ...` to recast.

Example:

```
if let theBike = theBike as? Wheeled  {
    print(theBike.numberOfWheels)
}
```

Comment: OP wants to "change the protocol conformance of an object". An `if let` block for casting allows them to recast a variable as a different protocol under the same name.

Comment: you pointed out the problem, it was wrong to declare a variable twice, even though the second time I changed a different conformance, but once a variable is declared it cannot change anymore, therefore, the second time declaration is invalided

Comment: as Bike conforms to Wheeled, this line should give  a warning that the optional cast will always succeed.

Comment: *Conditional cast from 'Bike' to 'Wheeled' always succeeds*

Comment: Nope. Because `theBike` is a variable of type `Vehicle` that may or may not conform to `Bike` or `Wheeled`. If you are unconvinced, open up Xcode and toy around with a playground.

Comment: I did. posted the warning.

Comment: Are you sure you are not casting `bike` instead of `theBike`?

Comment: you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `protocol<Vehicle, Wheeled>` to give it the type information of both `Vehicle` and `Wheeled`, while not using the type `Bike` directly.

```
let theBike: protocol<Vehicle, Wheeled> = bike
print(theBike.numberOfWheels)  // 0
print(theBike.owner)  // Bob
```

Comment: Yup. I always forget *that*. ;) I haven't found a place to use it yet.

Comment: @catalandres Thanks for the `protocol<Vehicle, Wheeled>` tips

Answer (score 1):

as Bike conforms to `Vehicle` and `Wheeled` you can just write them to variables of type `Vehicle` and `Wheeled`.

```
let bike: Bike = Bike()

let wheeled: Wheeled = bike
let vehikle: Vehicle = bike
```

But this isn't very useful as you can use `Bike` everywhere where a `Vehicle` or `Wheeled` is needed.

If you wha a code where you expect a `Wheeled` but later check, if it is also `Vehicle` it indicates a design issue.